# VBA Code to add comment only AFTER the INITIAL cell value is changed?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data entry form that let's users enter the data into specific cells. What i want is a way to track changes to the cell values. When the data entered initially through the entry form, i don't want that information to be tracked. However, if the user tries to change/edit the data that was entered then i want to add a comment to show the initial value and the amended one as well.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   Dim singlecell As Range

    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1000 Then Exit Sub

    For Each singlecell In Target

        If singlecell.Comment Is Nothing Then
            singlecell.AddComment Now & " - " & singlecell.Value & " - " & Environ("UserName")
        Else
            singlecell.Comment.Text _
                vbNewLine & Now & " - " & singlecell.Value & " - " & Environ("UserName") _
                , Len(singlecell.Comment.Text) + 1 _
                , False

        End If

        singlecell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True

    Next singlecell

End Sub
```

The code i tried adds a comment when the information from the entry form is submitted. However I don't need the comment to show just yet, I only want it when the user changes the initial cell value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a *helper* array to temporary store all of current cell comments and get the sensitive text out of the last recorded comment to compare with current cell content

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim singleCell As Range

    Dim commentsArray As Variant 'array to hold all singleCell comments
    Dim oldText As String ' string to hold last comment sensitive content

    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1000 Then Exit Sub


    For Each singleCell In Target

        If singleCell.Comment Is Nothing Then
            singleCell.AddComment Now & " - " & singleCell.Value & " - " & Environ("UserName")
        Else

            commentsArray = Split(singleCell.Comment.Text, vbNewLine) ' fill the array with current singleCell comments
            oldText = CStr(Split(commentsArray(UBound(commentsArray)), " - ")(1)) ' extract last recorded comment sensitive text

            'update comment if current cell value differs from last recorded comment sensitive text
            If oldText <> CStr(singleCell.Value2) Then _
                singleCell.Comment.Text _
                vbNewLine & Now & " - " & singleCell.Value & " - " & Environ("UserName") _
                , Len(singleCell.Comment.Text) + 1 _
                , False

        End If

        singleCell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The code did not work. I think the part that needs to be changed is the "nothing". What's the correct way of saying "If the cells contain initial values, do nothing, if they are changed then add comment"?

Comment: what does "not work" actually mean? I tested it and it worked as per your question requirements.

Comment: On my userform, when i click "submit" the information is stored on the respective cells. I do not want the comment to show at this point. I only want the comment to show if the user edits/change the information that was stored after hitting submit from the userform.

Answer (score -1):

Copy and create the same table in same sheet, have it hidden ,

```
Sub CopyCurrentTable()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With shtMapping
        .Range("E4:G1000").ClearContents 'which value to which value you are copying
        .Range("B4:D" & GetLastRow(shtMapping, "B", 4)).Copy ' starting postion
        .Range("E4").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With

End Sub
Sub LogAuditTrail()

    Dim colOld As Collection
    Dim colNew As Collection
    Dim objNew As ClsMapping
    Dim objOld As ClsMapping
    Set colOld = getMappingData("E")
    Set colNew = getMappingData("B")
    Dim sTS As String

    sTS = Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yyy hh:mm:ss")

    For Each objNew In colNew
        'Detect Items Changed
        If ItemIsInCollection(colOld, objNew.getKey) Then
            Set objOld = colOld(objNew.getKey)
            If objNew.isDifferent(objOld) Then
                Call PlotToAudit(objNew, objOld, sTS, "Change")
            End If
        Else
            'Detect Items Added
            Set objOld = New ClsMapping
            Call PlotToAudit(objNew, objOld, sTS, "New")
        End If
    Next objNew

    'Detect Items removed
    For Each objOld In colOld
        If Not ItemIsInCollection(colNew, objOld.getKey) Then
            Set objNew = New ClsMapping
            Call PlotToAudit(objNew, objOld, sTS, "Removed")
        End If
    Next objOld

End Sub

Sub PlotToAudit(obj1 As ClsMapping, obj2 As ClsMapping, sTS As String, sType As String)

    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = shtAudit.Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).Row

    If lRow = 3 Then
        lRow = 5
    ElseIf lRow = 1048576 Then
        MsgBox "Audit sheet is full. Contact Support." & vbNewLine & "No audit trail will be saved", vbCritical, "ERROR"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        lRow = lRow + 1
    End If

    With shtAudit
        .Unprotect g_sPassword
        .Range("B" & lRow).value = Application.UserName & "(" & Environ("USERNAME") & ")"
        .Range("C" & lRow).value = sTS
        .Range("D" & lRow).value = sType

        Select Case sType
            Case "Removed"
                .Range("E" & lRow).value = ""
                .Range("F" & lRow).value = ""
                .Range("G" & lRow).value = ""
                .Range("H" & lRow).value = obj2.FundCode
                .Range("I" & lRow).value = obj2.Subs
                .Range("J" & lRow).value = obj2.Reds
            Case "New"
                .Range("E" & lRow).value = obj1.FundCode
                .Range("F" & lRow).value = obj1.Subs
                .Range("G" & lRow).value = obj1.Reds
                .Range("H" & lRow).value = ""
                .Range("I" & lRow).value = ""
                .Range("J" & lRow).value = ""
            Case "Change"
                .Range("E" & lRow).value = obj1.FundCode
                .Range("F" & lRow).value = obj1.Subs
                .Range("G" & lRow).value = obj1.Reds
                .Range("H" & lRow).value = obj2.FundCode
                .Range("I" & lRow).value = obj2.Subs
                .Range("J" & lRow).value = obj2.Reds
        End Select
        With .Range("B" & lRow & ":J" & lRow)
            .Interior.Color = vbWhite
            .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuou
        End With
        .Protect g_sPassword
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes,i am new to stackoverflow,I do not know to tage it,,so thought this code would help him